# Adding Numbers with Letters attached

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of numbers:

```
19A
19B
20
21
22A
22B
```

I need it to add up the total of the entries but not count A and B as two.
So the above example I would need to be: 4. (19,20,21,22)

Comment: are the numbers always 2 digits ?

Comment: 2) Will there always be just one letter character? 3) Are the numeric portions always integers? 4) Are they always positive? Please click [edit] and answer the question in the comment above, plus my questions 2-4, by updating the question. The question is your channel lo us and should have all info needed to understand the problem; Add Comment is our channel to you.

Comment: Looks like you want a formula in the column to the right of your values which looks at the last character in each cell of the source. If the last character is a letter, copy everything but the letter to the destination; if it is a number, copy everything into the destination, and sum up all the destination column.  Is that an accurate description? See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/top-ten-ways-to-clean-your-data-2844b620-677c-47a7-ac3e-c2e157d1db19 and esp. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(A:A,1)="B"))
```

It give the total count less the count of items ending in *B*.

[image]